# Minitest warning: DEPRECATED global use of must_match. Use `_(obj)`

Tags: ruby, testing, minitest

I'm writing the following test with Minitest 5.12.0:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/http'

class NetClass; end

describe NetClass do
  attr_accessor :uri, :net
  before do
    @uri=URI('http://example.com/index.html')
    @net=Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  end

  it 'gets uri' do
    net.must_match /Example Domain/i
  end
end
```

The test succeeds but it outputs the warning:

> DEPRECATED: global use of must_match from net_test.rb:16 Use `_(obj).must_match` instead. This will fail in Minitest 6

To eliminate the warning I change the line:

```
net.must_match /Example Domain/i
```

to

```
_(net).must_match /Example Domain/i
```

I have not seen the `_(obj)` syntax before so my question is what is `_()` doing in this case.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is minitest-specific feature. From documentation:

```
  # Returns a value monad that has all of Expectations methods
  # available to it.
  #
  # Also aliased to #value and #expect for your aesthetic pleasure:
  #
  #         _(1 + 1).must_equal 2
  #     value(1 + 1).must_equal 2
  #    expect(1 + 1).must_equal 2
```

So, it is a wrapper that adds all needed testing methods to your object.

Implementation is following:

```
  def _ value = nil, &block
    Minitest::Expectation.new block || value, self
  end
```

You can dig into sources [here](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/96ba1dac6141599cce47ec298e7e72dc7d49812d/lib/minitest/spec.rb#L311-L313)

Comment: So I have hundreds of lines of code using the old syntax. Is there a way around this? I wonder if people maintaining these projects understand the meaning of backwards compatibility.

Comment: You can use a regex to find/replace all usages... for example, find all occurrences of `must_be_nil`, ignoring leading spaces: `([^ ]*).must_be_nil` and replace it with: `_($1).must_be_nil`